# Handling Date of Birth with <select> fields in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/) for a user registration form.

For the Date of Birth section of the form, I have a `<select>` field for day, month, and year.

So far, I have been using the `Fields` component of `redux-form` to capture each of the day, month, and year as separate variables:

```
const dobSelects = fields => {
  const { label, input } = fields;
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <select {...fields.day.input} name="dob" id="">
        <option />
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <select {...fields.month.input} id="">
        <option />
        <option value="january">January</option>
        <option value="february">February</option>
        <option value="march">March</option>
      </select>
      <select {...fields.year.input} id="">
        <option />
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This yields the following into my values to be submitted:

```
{day: "2", month: "january", year: "2002"}
```

However, what if I want to send one field as a `Date` object as opposed to three separate fields, while maintaining the same user interface?

I want the user to select the three fields, and instead of sending three separate fields, one `dateOfBirth` field as a `Date` object gets sent instead.

Furthermore, the `Fields` component of redux-form does not seem sufficient in this case because I cannot pass it a `validate` prop to validate the date of birth; I need to validate the three fields as one rather than separately.

How is this possible to achieve with redux-form?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `Fields` component create a custom field.  Here is the general idea:

```
class DOBSelects extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.buildState(props.input.value)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if(props.input.value !== this.props.input.value) {
            this.setState(this.buildState(props.input.value));
        }
    }

    buildState(value) {
        return value ? { 
            date: value.getDate(), 
            month: value.getMonth() + 1, year: 
            value.getFullYear()
        } : {
            date: '',
            month: '',
            year: ''
        }
    }

    update(state) {
        this.setState(state);

        const { date, month, year } = { ...this.state, ...state };
        const { onChange, value } = this.props.input;

        if(date && month && year) {
            onChange(new Date(year, month - 1, date));
        } else if(value) {
            onChange(null);
        }
    }

    render () {
        const { label, input: { name } } = this.props;
        const { date, month, year } = this.state
        const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor={name + '-day'}>
                {label}
            </label>
            <select onChange={e => { this.update({ date: e.target.value }); }} value={date} name={name + '-day'}>
                <option />
                {getOptions(1, 31)}
            </select>
            <select onChange={e => this.update({ month: e.target.value })} value={month} name={name + '-month'}>
                <option />
                {getOptions(1, 12)}
            </select>
            <select onChange={e => this.update({ year: e.target.value })} value={year} name={name + '-year'}>
                <option />
                {getOptions(thisYear - 20, thisYear)}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
  };
}

function getOptions(start, end) {
    const options = [];

    for(let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        options.push(<option key={i}>{i}</option>)
    }

    return options;
}
```

An even simpler solution would be to use something like [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) instead.

Comment: this looks like a good solution. However it still seems like a problem to provide validation for the Date object. I want to wait until the user has entered data into all three fields before it becomes `dirty`. As far as I've seen there's no way to achieve this with redux-form.

Comment: You'll need to use a stateful component to achieve this, I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: A date picker is not a good UX for birth date. Way too much navigation required for anyone over one year old. Dropdowns aren't great for year, either, unless the expected user group is of a very narrow age range.